# How to download folder artifact from artifactory

Tags: shell, artifactory

I need download artifact level folder from artifactory on shell script. I have found some same topics but I not found solution. Please give me solution.

Comment: Are you using PRO or OSS version? there is a solution for PRO version.

Comment: Yes, I use PRO version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A tip for non PRO users:

- Through the GUI go to the repository path (e.g. http://artifactory.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/list/libs-release-local/path/to/my/folder/
- Use the folder to recursively WGET the contents (e.g. wget -r --no-parent -nH --cut-dirs=4 --proxy=off http://artifactory.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/list/libs-release-local/path/to/my/folder/)

Comment: Also add:
`--reject html,md5,sha1`
and optionally add:
`-P path/to/output-directory`

Comment: You might also need `--user='my_user' --password='mypass'`

Answer (score 6):

When using the PRO version of Artifactory you can use [this REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) for downloading a complete folder.